# Amazon SNS: Create AWS Lambda API gateway, how to confirm subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I had a AWS lambda `my_lambda` which is configure API gateway. E.g: `https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{your-environment}/my_lambda`.

I also had a SNS `my_sns_topic`.

I create subscription API gateway to SNS topic successfully But it need to confirm subscription.

I don't know to how get token from Lambda API gateway. So I can use that token to confirm subscription.

p.s: The difficulty is my API gateway was created in Lambda function.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jackpop can you able to retrieve the `TOKEN` to confirm the `subscription`.If yes then pls share your answer. I am also stuck at the same usecase.